# Counting digits of number with no string operations

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to write a function which counts the number of digits in a number - with no `string` operation. here is my code:

```
def count_digits(n):
    count_list=[]
    while (n>0):
        n=n%10
        i=n
        count_list.append(i)
        n=n/10
        return len(count_list)

n=12345
print count_digits(n)
```

By using `%` i get the last digits - in order to add it to a list. By using `/` i throw the digit from the number.

The script does not work. For each `n` i put, the script just prints `1`.

Thanks!

Comment: The first time that n=n%10 is executed, n is reduced to a value between 0 and 9, regardless of its starting value.

Comment: `return` statement is not properly indented. It should be outside the `while` loop.

Comment: Also, maintaining the `count_list` when you could just use an incrementing counter seems kind of silly (only trick is that you handle `0` specially, or use a somewhat kludgy Python equivalent of `do`/`while` to avoid the need to handle it specially).

Comment: If you `import math`, you can get the number of digits using `int(math.log10(n)) + 1`

Comment: @eumiro: Cheater. ;-) (Note: I up-voted, but I suspect it would still count as cheating; this sounds like homework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems to your code:

- The `return` statement should be outside of the loop.
- The `n = n % 10` statement modifies `n`, making it impossible to get the other digits.
- I'd use the integer division operator `//`. In Python 3, `n / 10` would give a floating point number.
- Like ShadowRanger said, the current solution considers `0` as having `0` digits. You need to check whether `n` is `0`.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
def count_digits(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    count_list = []
    while n > 0:
        count_list.append(n % 10)
        n = n // 10
    return len(count_list)
```

Also, as it was said in the comments, since your goal is just to count the digits, you don't need to maintain a list:

```
def count_digits(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    count = 0
    while n > 0:
        n = n // 10
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: I'd also say that using a list is totally unnecessary, even if it is an acceptable solution

Comment: Note: This code (and the original) will treat `0` as having zero digits, when usually, it should still count as having one digit. It can be handled by either making the `while` condition `while True` with an `if n <= 0: break` at the end of the loop (so `0` gets counted once), or by adding an `if n == 0: return 1` to the top of the function. Obviously, still doesn't handle negative numbers (but handling them involves defining what digit count means; simplest would be to assign `n = abs(n)` at the top of the function and ignore the sign).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try this, a much simpler approach. No lists involved :)

```
def dcount(num):
    count = 0
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    while (num != 0):
        num /= 10
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

`count_list` stores the digits.

```
def count_digits(n):
    count_list=[]
    while (n>0):
        count_list.append(n%10)
        n-=n%10
        n = n/10
    return count_list

n=12345
print len(count_digits(n))
```

Without using a list

```
def count_digits(n):
   count_list=0
   while (n>0):
       count_list+=1
       n-=n%10
       n = n/10
   return count_list

n=12345
print count_digits(n)
```

Comment: Why do `n -= n % 10`? It makes `count_list` as `list` of 0s, which doesn't really matter (you just get the `len` of it anyway), but it costs more work for zero gain.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks

Comment: Still unnecessary. Switch to `n //= 10` (or `n = n // 10` if you prefer) and in both Py2 and Py3 it will do floor division; subtracting the remainder becomes unnecessary (and you remove the opportunity for floating point errors to bite you).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, It is `eskaev` solution, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Its working now but im not sure i understand WHY. I cant find the difference in the codes. I see that you changed it (to ' n- = n%10') but i cant understand the difference; if for example n=123, then n-=120. So we add an object (120) to the list. OK. But we just put Different object with keeping the same number of objects, no ?

Comment: @Amir Chazan  if for example n=123, it stores 3 in the list and do n-=n%10 (n=120), then n = n/10 (n=12) .the result list is `[3, 2, 1]`.