# Find number of digits in number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to generate a unique id for every user in my program. This is my code :

```
from random import choices
IDS = []
id = ""
num = int(input(" Entr the ids number : "))#عدد الايديات اللي بدك تسويها
len = int(input("Enter the length of the id:  "))#طول الايدي الواحد
def createId(num,len) :
        for i in range(num):
            id = ""
            for w in range(len):
                pl = str(choices([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])[0])
                id +=pl
                if id in IDS:
                    createId(1,len)
                else:
                    IDS.append(id)
                
def mll():
    len+=1
    createId(num,len)
    print(IDS)
    nn= 1
try:
    createId(num,len)
    print(IDS)
except :
    nn = 0
    while nn == 0 :
        try:
            mll()
        except:
            len +=1
```

But I have a problem. When I need to generate an id of 11 with length = 1, this is impossible. I need to increase the length to the minimum possible number of digits to accommodate the requested number.

How do I find how many digits a number has?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Obviously you cannot have more than 10 IDs if your length is 1. How to deal with this is up to your implementation (throw an error, automatically use the minimum length..)

Comment: @ApplePi You could work with a larger number system, like hexadecimal. Gets you up to 16 with one digit ;)

Comment: FYI, this isn't your issue, but you shouldn't be giving variables names that are the same as built-in functions, like `len` or `id`. You should rename those variables.

Comment: Yes but how to calculate minimum length for ex 11 id => len= 2

Comment: Can you describe, in words, what your program is supposed to do?

Comment: @Random Davis  How to calculate min number

Comment: Like 11 ids => len = 2

Comment: `len(str(id))` would do

Comment: Are you maybe looking to do what `hashlib` would do for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from uuid import uuid4

def create_a_numeric_unique_id(width: int) -> str:
        return str(uuid4().int)[:width]
```

Output:

```
create_a_numeric_unique_id(8) => '26045809'
```

Comment: and if you put an if statement ? `id=create_a_numeric_unique_id(8)  if id not in ids: ids.append(id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find how many digits a number has is:

```
len(str(num))
```

This converts the number to a string, then counts the number of characters in that string. (Note that you really do need to rename your `len` variable or else this won't work.)

If you'd like to do this working purely with numbers (which is more complicated but probably more efficient), see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494602/counting-digits-of-number-with-no-string-operations).